# Is it possible to use D3.js in a Excel add-in to make the charts in the add-in more reactive?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, office-js, excel-addins

I have the following code that I want to incorporate into my add-in. Will it be possible to do so? The following code was taken from a blog for interactive small multiples that is meant for creating responsive graphs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- include polyfills for custom event, Symbol and Custom Elements -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@6.26.0/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/custom-event-polyfill@0.3.0/custom-event-polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.8.0/document-register-element.js"></script>

<!-- use babel so that we can use arrow functions and other goodness in this block! -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script src="//unpkg.com/d3@5.5.0"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/d3fc@14.0.44"></script>

<style>
  body {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
  }
  .area {
    fill: #cec6b9;
  }
  #small-multiples > div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 185px;
    width: 50%
  }  
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    #small-multiples > div {
      width: 33%
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    #small-multiples > div {
      width: 25%
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    #small-multiples > div {
      width: 20%
    }
  }
  .tooltip .x-axis .tick {
    display: none;
  }
  .x-axis .domain, .x-axis .tick path,
  .y-axis .domain, .y-axis .tick path {
    display: none;
  }
  .plot-area {
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .x-axis {
    height: 1.5em !important;
  }
  .gridline-x {
    stroke: white;
  }
  .point {
    fill: black;
  }
  .point text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    font-size: 10px;
    stroke: none;
  }
  .bottom-handle {
    text-anchor: middle;
    alignment-baseline: hanging;
    font-size: 10px;
    transform: translateY(1.5em);
  }
  .top-handle {
    display: none;
  }
  .annotation-line line {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<div id='small-multiples'></div>

<script type='text/babel'>
d3.tsv('askmefi_category_year.tsv', (r) => ({
    category: r.category,
    n: Number(r.n),
    year: Number(r.year)
  }))
  .then((data) => {
    var nested = d3.nest()
        .key(k => k.category)
        .entries(data);
  
    nested.forEach(g => g.trackball = []);
      
    var yExtent = fc.extentLinear()
      .accessors([d => d.n])
        .pad([0, 0.2])
        .include([0]);
  
    var xExtent = fc.extentLinear()
        .accessors([d => d.year]);

    var area = fc.seriesSvgArea()
      .crossValue(d => d.year)
      .mainValue(d => d.n);
  
    var line = fc.seriesSvgLine()
      .crossValue(d => d.year)
      .mainValue(d => d.n);
  
    var gridlines = fc.annotationSvgGridline()
        .xTicks(0)
        .yTicks(3);
  
    var point = fc.seriesSvgPoint()
      .crossValue(d => d.year)
      .mainValue(d => d.value)
        .size(25)
        .decorate((selection) => {
        selection.enter()
            .append('text');        
        selection.select('text')
            .text(d => d.value)
      })
    
    var line = fc.annotationSvgLine()
        .orient('vertical')
      .value(d => d.year)
        .decorate((selection) => {
        selection.enter()
            .select('.bottom-handle')
            .append('text');        
        selection.select('.bottom-handle text')
            .text(d => d.year)
      })
     
  
    var multi = fc.seriesSvgMulti()
        .series([area, line, gridlines, line, point])
      .mapping((data, index, series) => {
        switch (series[index]) {
        case point:            
        case line:
          return data.trackball;
        default:
          return data.values;
        }
      });
  
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear();
    // create a chart
    var chart = fc.chartCartesian(
        xScale,
        d3.scaleLinear())
      .yDomain(yExtent(data))
        .xDomain(xExtent(data))
        .xLabel(d => d.key)
        .yTicks(3)
        .xTicks(2)
        .xTickFormat(d3.format('0'))
      .yOrient('left')
        .svgPlotArea(multi);
  
    function render() {
      // render
        var container = d3.select('#small-multiples')
      var update = container.selectAll('div.multiple')
        .data(nested);
      update.enter()
        .append('div')
        .classed('multiple', true)
        .merge(update)
        .call(chart)
        .classed('tooltip', d => d.trackball.length);

      // add the pointer component to the plot-area, re-rendering
      // each time the event fires.
      var pointer = fc.pointer()
        .on('point', (event) => {
          // determine the year
          if (event.length) {
            var year = Math.round(xScale.invert(event[0].x));
            // add the point to each series
            nested.forEach((group) => {
              var value = group.values.find(v => v.year === year);
              group.trackball = [{
                year: year,
                value: value.n
              }];
            })
          } else {
            nested.forEach(g => g.trackball = [])
          }
          render();
        });

      d3.selectAll('#small-multiples .plot-area')
        .call(pointer);  
    }
  
    render();
    });
 


</script>
```

Here, obviously the code imports a CSV file and works with that. Can office.js also work along with D3.js without importing any CSV file?